# Product of paracompact and compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space, paracompactness

> “If $X$ is paracompact and $Y$ is compact, then $X \times Y $ is also paracompact.”

> From this , if $X$ is a discrete space and $Y = \{0, 1\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, Y, \{0\}\}$, then the product space $X × Y$ is paracompact.

How  I can show that $Y$ is compact? Is it enough to say "since $Y$ is finite then $Y$ is compact" and why $X$ is paracompact?

Comment: $X$ is paracompact because you are assuming it.

Comment: It is not hard to show $X$ is paracompact since singleton sets are open in $X$ (take a refinement of a cover $C$ to be the collection of all singletons taken from members of $C$).

Comment: how i can show that Y is compact ?

Comment: $Y$ is compact since there are only 3 open sets.

Comment: if we want to show a set is compact we must show that for any open cover of Y is has a finite subcover can you help me how i can use this to prove that Y is compact

Comment: Any open cover has at most 3 sets.  The cover itself serves as the required finite subcover.

Comment: A finite space is always compact so the theorem applies with this $Y$. $X$ is paracompact trivially (use singletons) or by the theorem that all metric spaces are paracompact; take your pick.